# Can I chain / nest template literal types in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Say I want a type that matches `az | xq`. Can I do something like this?

```
type First = 'a' | 'x'
type Second<F extends First> = F extends 'a' ? 'z' : 'q'
type Both = `${First}${Second<First>}` // wrong
const bothGood: Both = 'az' // :)
const bothBad:  Both = 'aq' // not an error :(
```

(Obviously in this trivial case I can just define the union; the question is whether there's a way to chain together a template literal like this to make more complicated conditional literal types.)

I can do something like this:

```
type Both<S> = S extends Second<infer F> ? `${F}${S}` : never
const bothGood: Both<'z'> = 'az'
const bothBad:  Both<'z'> = 'aq'
```

But I'm not sure that buys me much since the whole point is to infer the `z | q` part.

Is there a way I can define a *non-generic* type `Both` that only matches `az | xq` using nested template literals like this?

Comment: I think you're question is a little vague. Are you basically looking for a type that will take two unions like `"a" | "b" | "c"` and `"x" | "y" | "z"` and produce a union that looks like this?: `"ax" | "by" | "cz"`?

Comment: @Jordan What I'm looking for would not in general be just a product or zip of unions; that's just a simple example. I'm looking to support arbitrary conditional logic where the second "segment" depends on the content of the first. So it could be `F extends 'a' ? (<some complicated thing here>)`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to *distribute* the `` `${First}${Second<First>}` `` operation across the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) members of `First`.  That is, break `First` up into its union members `F`, compute `` `${F}${Second<F>}` `` for each one, and then combine the results into another union.

There are multiple ways to do this; the one I present here will be to make a *distributive object type* as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  It looks like this:

```
type Both = { [F in First]: `${F}${Second<F>}` }[First]
// type Both = "az" | "xq"
```

This works by making a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) with one property for every member `F` in the `First` union, where each property value is the corresponding `` `${F}${Second<F>}` ``.  Then we immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) that mapped type with `First`, producing a union of all those property values.  Any type of the form `{[P in K]: G<P>}[K]` is a distributive object type which distributes the `G<P>` operation over union members of `K`.

And let's make sure it behaves how you want:

```
const bothGood: Both = 'az' // okay
const bothBad: Both = 'aq' // error
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgJwM7CgXigcgIaagHywA9MAoUSKAZQgGMB7AOwBMAeGKCI4CFpWRCgB86WJ269m-HHgD8WAF54AXFgCOZCtABC9YAAtRAbygBtDnEYDkwALqqABgBIjMAL4uaDFuyFuHUG7mgnakAPRhUFpQugaiAETYCvEEUPFEavGkpN4oUABGevoA4vT0zKqxhhg4SlARUPQA1tggOUx5hQba2BUxRaI4GvWREAgI9AhAA)